# Insert user into SharePoint group with HTTP request

Tags: rest, sharepoint

I am using a HTTP request connector to insert a user into SharePoint.  In all transparency this is using MS Flow/Power Automate.

I have the URL that reads users from the SharePoint group.

https://**MYCOMPANY**.sharepoint.com/sites/planning-test/_api/web/SiteGroups/GetById(37)/Users

My **header** is constructed as:

```
{
  "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
  "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose"
}
```

The request **body** is constructed as:

```
{
'_metadata':{'type':'SP.User'},
‘LoginName’:’i:0#.f|membership|dducolon@starbucks.com’
}
```

which is giving me a status output code of "**400**"

and I get a verbose error that says:

*Invalid JSON. The property name '' is not valid. The name of a
property cannot be empty. clientRequestId:
f6aec2b4-822d-4a6e-90e9-f4aa0162d182 serviceRequestId:
b499689f-e0a8-0000-6122-5f43f6ec0327*

Does anybody know why I would be getting an error that says my property is blank?

[Image of "Send an HTTP request to SharePoint" in MS Flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eEG7b.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this body:

```
{       
              '__metadata': {
                // Type that you are modifying.
                'type': 'SP.User'
            },
                'LoginName': 'i:0#.f|membership|dducolon@starbucks.com'
            }
```

Your quotes are wrong,and there should be two _ before metadata.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like on the second line of the body the single quotes are back quotes and not the expected ' quote.  This comes from copy paste in the PowerAutomate UI.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I got exact same error because of additional brackets:

```
{
    "__metadata": {
        "type": "SP.Data.TestListListItem"
    },
    
   {
        "Title": "dddd",
        "AnotherColumn": "xxxx"
   }
}
```

Notice there should not be brackets enclosing column names and their values.